# How to use inheritance in relation to MongoRepositories in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oop, inheritance

In my program I have a abstract class "user" which the objects "business" and "customer" inherit from. I am wanting to put some methods inside "UserService" which the other two objects services will make use of. Now in one of these methods I need to call a repository like so.

```
userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail);
```

Now my problem is that, the other two objects will have problems using the method that contains that line as they will need to have their own repositories (BusinessRepository and CustomerRepository). So my question is, how can I get those two sub repositories to inherit from the userRepository so I dont have to override each method with its respective repository.

```
public interface BusinessRepository extends MongoRepository<Business, String>

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>
```

As you can see there will be issues with the object type if I simply get business Repository to extend UserRepository, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an interface that doesn't extend from MongoRepository but has all the methods in it:

```
public interface UserRepositoryModel<T extends User>{
    T findByEmail(String email);
    //other methods
}
```

And then have the other Repositories extend from this one, too:

```
@Repository
public interface BusinessRepository extends MongoRepository<Business, String>, UserRepositoryModel<Business> { }

@Repository
public interface CutomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Cutomer, String>, UserRepositoryModel<Customer>{ }
```